A die is thrown as long as necessary for an ace to turn up.
A die is thrown as long as necessary for an ace to turn up.

Given that the ace does not turn up at the first throw, what is the probability that more than three throws will be necessary?

I believe this is conditional probability. Isn't it?
If $H$ is the event "more than 3 throws" and A the event "ace does not turn up on the first throw", then
$$\mathbb{P}(H|A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(AH)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=\frac{(\frac{5}{6})^3}{\frac{5}{6}}=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$$
which is the same answer as the text book, so i feel this is correct.

Suppose that the number, $n$, of throws is even. What is the probability that $n=2$?

This one feels like its just $\mathbb{P}(\text{not ace at first throw})$ * $\mathbb{P}(\text{Ace at the second throw})=\frac{5}{36}$ or $\mathbb{P}(\text{n=2 | n is even})$, which I do not know how to calculate. The text book says its $1-(\frac{5}{6})^2$, which looks like the complement of the event described in the previous question, and for me that doesn't make sense, since the complement would be "ace does not turn up at first throw, and it takes three or less throws.
Any help is appreciated.

+1 : to your question for two reasons: [1] Good work shown on the 1st question, which you have every reason to suspect is (somehow) linked to the 2nd question. [2] I (also) am unable to follow the book's analysis to the 2nd question.  So, I can't really expect you to show work trying to justify the book's analysis, which you (quite reasonably) do not understand.

For what's it's worth, I (also) was not able to follow the book's explanation.  However, my approach (below) yields the same answer.

For the 2nd question:

Let $~A~$ denote the event that the number of throws is equal to $~2.~$

Let $~B~$ denote the event that the number of throws are even.


Then, the desired computation is
$$p(A|B) = \frac{p(AB)}{p(B)} = \frac{p(A)}{p(B)}. \tag1 $$
Then,
$$p(A) = \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{5}{36},$$
and
$$p(B) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \text{probability that it takes 2k dice throws}$$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{5}{36} \times \left[ ~1 + \frac{25}{36} + \left( ~\frac{25}{36} ~\right)^2 + \left( ~\frac{25}{36} ~\right)^3 + \cdots ~\right]. \tag2 $$
The expression in (2) above is easy to evaluate, from the formula for a geometric sequence:
$$1 + x + x^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1 - x} ~: ~|x| < 1.$$
So,
$$p(B) = \frac{5}{36} \times \frac{1}{1 - \frac{25}{36}} = \frac{5}{36} \times \frac{36}{11} = \frac{5}{11}.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{p(A)}{p(B)} = \frac{5/36}{5/11} = \frac{11}{36}.$$

For the first part, since we are given that the first throw is not an ace, an alternative way to  compute the required probability would be P(the next two throws are also not aces) $= \left(\dfrac56\right)^2$
For the second part, presumably you need to to incorporate the conditions of the first part, although the way you have written it disjointly, it is not evident.
For an ace  to occur on an even throw, $n=2,4,6,...$
But we have already computed $P(n>3) = \left(\dfrac56\right)^2$
so P(ace occurs at $n=2) = 1 - \left(\dfrac56\right)^2$

+1 also for your answer, which is clearly better than mine.  In fact, I had to read your answer twice to understand it.

To tell you the truth, given my limited knowledge of probability theory, even now, I am unsure whether your approach is valid.  That is, it is unclear to me that $$\frac{p(n=2)}{p\left( ~n ~\text{is even} ~\right)}$$ is supposed to not coincidentally equal $~\displaystyle p(n < 3), ~$ given that $~p(n=1) =0.$

If $X$ is the number of throws needed then:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=2|X \text{ is even}) =\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=2 \cap X \text{ is even})}{\mathbb{P}(X \text{ is even})}$$
The value of the numerator you already had found and can be computed as:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=2 \cap X \text{ is even})=\frac{5}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}=\frac{5}{36}$$
The denominator can be computed as:
$$\mathbb{P}(X \text{ is even})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(X =2n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2n-1}\times\frac{1}{6}\right]=\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{5}{6}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2\right)^n=\frac{5}{36}\times\frac{1}{1-\frac{25}{36}}=\frac{5}{11}$$
So we can compute the probability as $$\frac{\frac{5}{36}}{\frac{5}{11}}=\frac{11}{36}=1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$$
